# How to add SHT11 sensor to sysfs

Tags: sysfs

a few days ago I decided to connect to the SMBus bus in my computer SHT11 sensor. I have no idea how to add this sensor to sysfs. This sensor is quite specific in that it uses the address 0x00 and such can not be put in new_device:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo sht15 0x00 >  /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device'
```

bash: line 0: echo: write error: wrong argument

when i try put 0x50, there's no error:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo sht15 0x50 >  /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device'
```

it creates folder /sys/bus/i2c/devices/0-0050, but without measurements

Answer (score 1):

SHT11 and SHT15 from [Sensirion](http://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity/Sensirion_Humidity_SHT1x_Datasheet_V5.pdf) are not I2C enabled sensors. They have 2 wire communication (data and Clock) but they are not I2C as you can verify by the link above.

Linux has a driver (sht15.c) for this sensor when they are tied to GPIOs.